# How can I convert an array of hashes to an array of hash values?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of hashes:

```
[{"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"female"}]
```

How can I convert it to array of values:

```
["male", "male", "female"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic approach to this that would take into account other possible keys:

```
list = [{"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"female"}]

# Collect the 'sex' key of each hash item in the list.
sexes = list.collect { |e| e['sex'] }
```

Comment: I like this approach in case there are more keys than just the desired one. +1

Answer (score 4):

In this case,

```
[{"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"female"}].map(&:values).flatten
```

should work.

It takes an array from each hash, then flatten the nested array.

Answer (score 4):

```
[{"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"female"}].flat_map(&:values)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [{"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"female"}]
arr.map(&:values).flatten
```

EDIT: As directed by @tadman. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to in-place flatten on an intermediate value. `flatten` will do the job.

Comment: @tadman Right. :) I just considered it, incase AdamNYC wished to retain them in the same array.

Comment: That `flatten!` call only affects the result of the `map` operation, and does not modify `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

You can "map" the elements inside array, take the values of hashes, them "flatten" the resultant array.

```
[{"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"female"}].map{|h| h.values }
=> [["male"], ["male"], ["female"]]

[["male"], ["male"], ["female"]].flatten
=> ["male", "male", "female"]
```

In a single line, you can:

```
[{"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"female"}].map{|h| h.values }.flatten
```

or:

```
[{"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"male"}, {"sex"=>"female"}].map(&:values).flatten
```

Docs:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map

Comment: -1 for posing an answer 12 minutes after an answer with the same solution was posted.

Comment: It is more thorough, but this exact solution has already been posted three times. Unlike being fashionably late to the party, this is just redundant.

Comment: Sorry, I don't knew that it was a race. Should I write lighting fast for  earn some points the next time? I was trying to give a good answer, that include search something else. Sorry if I'm not fast enough.

Comment: It's not a race per se, it's a contest to provide the best answer, which is measured in efficiency and clarity, basically coming down the most Ruby-like often. Of course, being first with that helps, but often someone will post much later, with a more thought-out and comprehensive answer, and win the day. Some OPs grab the first answer without any knowledge of what would make the best answer, so you'll see a negative score for the selected answer, and another answer with a very high positive score.

Answer (score -2):

```
    arr = Array.new 
    my_hash.each do |el|
      #collect them here...
      arr.push(el["sex"]);
    end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't transform, it just prints. You've left out the critical part of this. Not really an answer, is it?

Comment: I did write where he would collect them... so here it is corrected
Thank you

Comment: There are several other answers which provide this functionality. This non-answer should be removed.